# How to select list items in a nested list in Python

Tags: python, list

If I have a list such as:

```
lst3 = [[1, 2, "ABC"],["EF", 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Is there a way to select the number 2 and the number 7 from within their nested lists?

Answer (score 3):

Just access them through their indexes:

```
print(lst3[0][1])
print(lst3[1][3])
```

**Output**

```
2
7
```

Answer (score 2):

Just target them using their corresponding indexes:

```
lst3 = [[1, 2, "ABC"],["EF", 5, 6, 7, 8]]
# ------0^-1^---2^------0^--1^-2^-3^-4^---
# ------|    0      |-|        1        |

print(lst3[0][1]) # 2
print(lst3[1][3]) # 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the negative indexe `-2` to access the second last element:

```
items = [l[-2] for l in lst3]
```

Example:

```
>>> lst3 = [[1, 2, "ABC"],["EF", 5, 6, 7, 8]]
>>> [l[-2] for l in lst3]
[2, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lst3[0][1],lst3[1][3]

 >>>(2,7)
```

Answer (score 0):

To select an item from a nested list, you first give the position of the nested list in the initial list, and then the position of the item in the nested list.
For example:
to get 2 you type: `lst3[0][1]`
to get 7 you type: `lst3[1][3]`
and so on...